# Css selector > + #id + hover syntax confusion

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

I have a few buttons and one of them has a different colour so the hover colour I chose for the other doesn't quite work with that one. Therefore I wanted to create an #id for it. Here are the CSS and HTML:

/!\ the id i wanted to make is the very last css in the code provided here. I saw confusion in the replies, .boutonsim is just the class for all of the buttons while #boutonachat is the id thing.

However the id thing has 0 effect. idk how to do the syntax for that.

```
.boutonsim { /*construction d'un bouton avec faux fond*/
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.9em;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.top-container > button {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'CapitalisTypOasis', 'CapitalisTypOasisMedium';
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.9em;
    padding: 0;
}


.top-container > button:hover {
    color: brown;
}

.top-container > button:hover {
    color: rosybrown;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="top-container">
        <img id="img2" src="images/haut.png" />
        <img id="title" src="images/nom.png" />
        <img id="logo" src="images/LOGO.png" />

        <div class="boutonsim" style="right: 80px;" name="boutonachat"> <!--image-->
            <img src="images/clipart/boutonORIGINALachat.png" /> <!--vrai bouton-->
        </div>
        <button id="boutonachat" style="right: 80px;">Billets</button>

        <div class="boutonsim" style="right: 280px;" name="boutonculture"> <!--image-->
            <img src="images/clipart/boutonORIGINAL.png" /> <!--vrai bouton-->
        </div>
        <button style="right: 280px;">Culture</button>

        <div class="boutonsim" style="right: 480px;" name="boutonpaysages"> <!--image-->
            <img src="images/clipart/boutonORIGINAL.png" /> <!--vrai bouton-->
        </div>
        <button style="right: 480px;">Paysages</button>

        <div class="boutonsim" style="right: 680px;" name="boutonaccueil"> <!--image-->
            <img src="images/clipart/boutonORIGINAL.png" /> <!--vrai bouton-->
        </div>
        <button style="right: 680px;">Accueil</button>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to apply different colors I'd just refer them with "button:nth-of-type(1):hover"

Answer (score 2):

When calling an ID in CSS, you must use "#" instead of "." - which is used for classes.

In other words to continue your declaration and actually see a result you would need to write:

```
#boutonachat { /*construction d'un bouton avec faux fond*/
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.9em;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Inline Styling for Color:

```
 <button style="right: 80px; background-color: red;">Billets</button>
```

Comment: it's not this one, the id i wanted to make was #boutonachat

Comment: If you are already giving the class a background color, I wouldn't recommend giving an ID an overriding color; if anything take the color out of the class and assign it with ID's alone. However in this case it couldn't hurt just to apply "inline styling" to get the job done on that specific button. I will update my answer